# How do I loop this webscrape/tweet script 24/7?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter, tweepy

Just started learning Python. I am trying to gather data by webscraping and tweet out info. But everytime I rerun the code. I get

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
187 - Status is a duplicate.
```

How do I loop this script without getting this error?

Here's my code :

```
def scrape ():
    page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    home = soup.find(class_="editorial-franchise-layout__main__3cLBl")
    posts = home.find_all(class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__inherit-font__1Y8w3 text__inherit-size__1DZJi link__underline_on_hover__2zGL4")
    top_post = posts[0].find("h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").find_all("span")[0].text.strip()
    
    tweet (top_post)
```

```
def tweet (top_post):
    api_key = 'deletedforprivacy'
    api_key_secret = 'deletedforprivacy'
    access_token = 'deletedforprivacy'
    access_token_secret = 'deletedforprivacy'
    authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
    authenticator.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    api.update_status(f"{top_post} \nSource : https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/")
    print(top_post)
    
        
scrape()
```

Comment: It is possible that Reuters limits you to a certain number of requests per hour or per day, and you have exceeded the limit.

Comment: I think it was because of tweepy. When i ran it the first time. It tweeted it no problem. but when I reran the same tweet. It gives the duplicate error. The reason I know is because when I change the structure of api.update_status(f"{top_post} \nSource : https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/") it doesn't give me the duplicate error

Answer (score 0):

The twitter api checks if the content is duplicate and if it is duplicate it returns:

```
 Request returned an error: 403 {"detail":"You are not allowed to create a Tweet with duplicate content.","type":"about:blank","title":"Forbidden","status":403}
```

I added an simple function to check if the previous content is same as the one about to be added

** Full Code**

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

user_id = 000000000000000  # Get userid from https://tweeterid.com/
bearer_token = "<BEARER_TOKEN>"
consumer_key = "<CONSUMER_KEY>"
consumer_secret = "<CONSUMER_SECRET>"


def init():

    # Get request token
    request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write"
    oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

    try:
        fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
    except ValueError:
        print(
            "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
        )

    resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
    resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
    print("Got OAuth token and secret")

    # Get authorization
    base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
    print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)
    verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: ")

    # Get the access token
    access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        consumer_key,
        client_secret=consumer_secret,
        resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
        resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
        verifier=verifier,
    )
    oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)

    access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
    access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]

    # Make the request
    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        consumer_key,
        client_secret=consumer_secret,
        resource_owner_key=access_token,
        resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
    )
    scraper(oauth, bearer_token)


def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2UserTweetsPython"
    return r


def previous_tweet():
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/tweets".format(user_id)

    # Tweet fields are adjustable.
    # Options include:
    # attachments, author_id, context_annotations,
    # conversation_id, created_at, entities, geo, id,
    # in_reply_to_user_id, lang, non_public_metrics, organic_metrics,
    # possibly_sensitive, promoted_metrics, public_metrics, referenced_tweets,
    # source, text, and withheld
    params = {"tweet.fields": "text"}
    response = requests.request(
        "GET", url, auth=bearer_oauth, params=params)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    # checking if this is the first post
    if response.json() != {'meta': {'result_count': 0}}:
        # Since twitter changes html to small url I am splitting at \n to match to new payload
        previous_tweet_text = response.json()["data"][0]["text"].split("\n")[0]
        previous_payload = {"text": f"{previous_tweet_text}"}
    else:
        previous_payload = {"text": f""}

    return previous_payload


def scraper(oauth, bearer_token):
    while True:
        page = requests.get(
            "https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        home = soup.find(class_="editorial-franchise-layout__main__3cLBl")
        posts = home.find_all(
            class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__inherit-font__1Y8w3 text__inherit-size__1DZJi link__underline_on_hover__2zGL4")
        top_post = posts[0].find(
            "h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").find_all("span")[0].text.strip()
        # Be sure to add replace the text of the with the text you wish to Tweet. You can also add parameters to post polls, quote Tweets, Tweet with reply settings, and Tweet to Super Followers in addition to other features.
        payload = {
            "text": f"{top_post}\nSource:https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/"}
        current_checker_payload = {"text": payload["text"].split("\n")[0]}
        previous_payload = previous_tweet()
        if previous_payload != current_checker_payload:
            tweet(payload, oauth)
        else:
            print("Content hasn't changed")
        time.sleep(60)


def tweet(payload, oauth):

    # Making the request
    response = oauth.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets",
        json=payload,
    )

    if response.status_code != 201:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text)
        )

    print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

    # Showing the response as JSON
    json_response = response.json()
    print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```

** Output**

```
Response code: 201
{
"data": {
    "id": "1598558336672497664",
    "text": "FTX ex-CEO Bankman-Fried claims he was unaware of improper use of customer funds -ABC News\nSource:URL" #couldn't post short url in stackoverflow
  }
}

Content hasn't changed
Content hasn't changed
Content hasn't changed
```

[image: Output image]

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: It keeps giving me : UnboundLocalError                        

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fetch_response' referenced before assignment

Comment: Yes it is the api key and secret key right?

Comment: also, this site is not found  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write

Comment: the site is not accessible since you haven't provided the consumer creds in browser.

Comment: check if the creds provided by you is correct

Comment: when you run this you will be shown an URL in the command prompt and then you have to go to that site to authenticate first and then input the pin provided by the site in the command prompt.

Comment: I got the pin then I got this : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [284], line 96
     92     print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
     95 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 96     init()

Cell In [284], line 47, in init()
     40 # Make the request
     41 oauth = OAuth1Session(
     42     consumer_key,
     43     client_secret=consumer_secret,
     44     resource_owner_key=access_token,
     45     resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
     46 )

Comment: ---> 47 scrape(oauth)

TypeError: scrape() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: i had a typo its scraper and not scrape. sorry for this

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! how can I run this 24/7? and how often will it check the reuters website to scrape data?

Comment: it will check every 60 seconds. Change time.sleep(60) to your desired timespan. I don't know about hosting it 24/7 since it requires auth pin. you could run the code in kaggle or colab but they have runtime limits. It will help if you have poor internet or electricity connection.

Comment: I tried to run the script again and it gave me this error : Exception: Request returned an error: 403 {"detail":"You are not allowed to create a Tweet with duplicate content.","type":"about:blank","title":"Forbidden","status":403}